# Dynamic div side by side

Tags: jquery, css

It's a possibility that I'm asking a duplicate question. I searched on SO and nothing came close to my problem nor did I find any helpful answers. I am relatively new in the CSS world so any help would be appreciated.

I have two div inside a container which I want to put side by side. Inside the second div, I am placing an icon which is not fixed. If some condition was satisfied then that icon would hide. Another requirement is that When the window shrinks, I want both elements to show and preferably shrinking div1 and making the icon intact and the same size so that both are visible.

```
<div class="main-container">
            <div class="div1"></div>
            <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Following CSS worked for me and satisfies all my requirements, but not working on IE10 because of flex.

```
.main-container
{
    display: flex;
}

.div1
{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid <#=styles["subduedBorderColor"]#>;
    background-color: <#=styles["controlBackgroundColor"]#>;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 6px 2px 0 16px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I tried another approach here, but div1 had a fixed size and looking bad when icon is not present. I want div1 to take the full space when no icon is there.

```
.main-container
{
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%
}

.div1
{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid <#=styles["subduedBorderColor"]#>;
    background-color: <#=styles["controlBackgroundColor"]#>;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 6px 2px 0 16px;
    width: 85%; /* fallback if needed */
    width: calc((100%) - 50px);
    display: inline-block;
}

.div2
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I am struggling since yesterday, and really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: use `float:left` on `.div1` css

Comment: Thanks Parth, I tried that but that didn't help

Comment: Can you make fiddle for this?

Comment: You need to give `float:left` to all div1 and div2. Use `css` `.main-container div{float:left;}`

Comment: If it dosn't help then you need to put screen shot or sample so anyone can help you more.

Comment: So you want right div to be same as size of icon and left div to take rest of space?

Comment: yes, here is the fiddle link, with flex: https://jsfiddle.net/xzdmts8b/                                     without flex: https://jsfiddle.net/ojq9pLhb/, using fiddle first time, so this is what i close to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following css worked for me on IE10, see the fallback I added for IE10. I know this will not work for older IE but I am fine with that as long as it is working for IE10+, Chrome and Firefox.

```
.div1
{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid <#=styles["subduedBorderColor"]#>;
    background-color: <#=styles["controlBackgroundColor"]#>;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 6px 2px 0 16px;
    -ms-flex: auto; /* IE 10 */
    flex: auto;
}

.main-container
{
    display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE 10 */
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to give the container a relative position then give the two div inside an absolute position see [JSFIDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/27xm88js/)

```
.main-container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  background: blue;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
}

.div1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: but this looks fixed size of div1 and div2, half red and half blue. can I make  completely red?

Comment: in my case div1 has a toolbar and div2 has icon. In some case i just need to show toolbar without icon and that time I want to keep full space for toolbar. In other case I want to show both toolbar and icon, this way I believe above I can't use.